# Weird time series plot with Python when adding date to x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib pyplot for plotting a time series of about 15000 observations. When I use this code for plotting without an x-axis data points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(15,10)})
sns.set_palette("husl")
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5), dpi=80)
plt.plot(df['INTC'])
plt.show()
```

I get this, which is the plot I expect

[image]

The matter is that when I add the date as data points for the x-axis:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5), dpi=80)
plt.plot(df['Date'],df['INTC'])
plt.show()
```

The same time series gets plotted in a weird manner:

[image]

The df looks like this:

```
index   Date                    INTC
0       2022-02-04 09:30:00     47.77
1       2022-02-04 09:31:00     47.96
2       2022-02-04 09:32:00     47.81
3       2022-02-04 09:33:00     47.73
4       2022-02-04 09:34:00     47.57
...
```

Every observation has a time separation of 1 minute. What should I do to plot it properly *including* the date points in the x-axis? Thanks.

Comment: I think we can add the x-axis labels to the code for the first graph, using the time series data as a string. `plt.xticks(np.arange(15000), df['Date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Seems to work to show all the dates. The thing is that it takes a lot of time to compute, and I would like it to appear with only the dates that fit in the axis, as in the second image.

Comment: Then the tick points and tick strings need to be thinned out. `plt.xticks(np.arange(15000)[::2000], df['Date'][::2000].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`This is now 2000 pieces spaced.

Comment: Thank you. That works fine! The only thing is that I had to call the `.dt` attribute of the Date column before the `strftime`. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Don’t just label the index with dates as @r-beginners is suggesting.  Properly convert your dates. If your Date is properly datetimes already, then check that you _actually_ have data in those gaps.